# How to cast a php string in float without defaulting to '0' in case of real string

Tags: php

I fill an array with data coming from xml.
Therefore, numbers come as string and strings such as 'n/a' comes also as strings.
Then I need to push this data to a mysql db column as float.
I need to numbers to float but everything else should be null instead of '0' as most of the methods below are actually doing.

```
$array = [
"125.5",
85.5,
"n/a",
"0",
null
];

echo "floatval \n";
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item . ' -> ' . floatval($item) . "\n";
}
echo "type cast \n";
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item . ' -> ' . (float)$item . "\n";
}
```

This code outputs this:

```
floatval 
125.5 -> 125.5
85.5 -> 85.5
n/a -> 0
0 -> 0
 -> 0
type cast 
125.5 -> 125.5
85.5 -> 85.5
n/a -> 0
0 -> 0
 -> 0
```

Do you have any clever solution rather then actually testing all potential fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want numeric strings to be cast to float, [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric) check should work:

```
$value = is_numeric($item) ? (float) $item : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the documentation says it will most likely return 0 for strings.
You could write a custom function like

```
function convertToFloat($num): float|null {
    if (!is_numeric($num)) {
        return null;
    }
    return floatval($num);
}
```